# why i can't execute after system("CLS")?

Tags: c

i can't execute after typing password. it gives me a force closed on windows. i'm not good at C. Anyone can help me?

```
    int i;
    char user, pass[4], pwd, a;

    printf("insert Username         : ");
    scanf("%s", &user);

    printf("insert Password <4 char>    : ");
    scanf("%c", &pass);

        for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
         pwd = getch();
         pass[i] = pwd;
         pwd = '*' ;
         printf("%c",pwd);
        }
        pass[i] = '\0';
        printf("\n");
        system("pause");
        system("CLS");

        printf("username %s", user);

        getch();
        system("pause");
```

Comment: to start: this declaration: char user; only has room for one character. then this line: scanf("%s", &user); is allowing the user to input any length of the user string, including a zero length. Suggest: char user[20]; and if( 1 != scanf(" 19s", user) ) { //handle error} consumes any leading 'white space', will limit the user to input a max of 19 characters, so no buffer overflow possible, and handle any input errors, such as the user only typing the 'return' key

Comment: this line: `scanf("%c", &pass);` will only allow the user to input a single character, AND that character will be the newline '\n' left in the input stream from the user entering the 'user' name.   Always check the returned value (not the parameter value) from a call to scanf() to assure the operation was successful.   Suggest: `if( 1 != scanf(" %3s", &pass) ) { // handle error }

Comment: for readabiliy/understandability by us humans, please consistently indent the code.  never use tabs for indenting as each wordprocessor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set differently.  suggest using 4 spaces for indenting as that is wide enough to be seen, even with variable width fonts.   suggest indent after every opening brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}'   it is also a good practice, for readability, to place a blank line between code blocks

Comment: this line: `pass[i] = '\0';` will place the '\0' past the end of the pass[] buffer.   this is undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.  This is because the previous 'for' loop stops when 'i' is = 4, the pass[] buffer is only 4 long and in C, the max index is 1 less than the length of the buffer (indexing starts at 0, not 1) so pass[4] is 1 past the end of the buffer

Comment: the function: `getch()` is not portable.  strongly suggest calling: `getchar()` instead

Comment: when you have a runtime problem, post code the cleanly compiles, is minimal in size, and still demonstrates the problem.  The posted code doesn't even come close to compiling and we are not interested in guessing what parts of the code are needed to be added to make it compile.

Comment: the loop that reads the password buffer `pass[]` will output the '*' in the next cursor location, not overlay the current character.   suggest turning off 'echo' while entering the password, when each char is read, move the cursor left one space and output the '*'.  Then after the complete password is entered, then re-enable the echo.  While entering the password, watch for a newline and other special characters that need to be acted upon, like backspace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When output is to a terminal, stdio is line-buffered by default. So you won't see the output of `printf()` until you print a newline (or print enough to fill the buffer), or explicitly flush the buffer. So change to:

```
printf("username %s\n", user);
```

or call `fflush(stdout)` after that `printf`.

The `CLS` has nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your string `pass[4]` is too short. After the loop

```
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
```

the var `i` will be `4`. You then write beyond the end of the array with

```
pass[i] = '\0';
```

which is **Undefined Behaviour** and can easily break the system. Also your formatting methods are reversed between char and string. You have

```
scanf("%s", &user);
...
scanf("%c", &pass);
```

These should be

```
scanf("%c", &user);
...
scanf("%s", pass);        // don't use the & here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                              // char user[6];
 scanf("%s", &user);          // scanf("%5s",user);
```

`user` is char variable . It can't contain more than one character . Use a char array.

```
scanf("%c", &pass);         // use this scanf("%3s",pass);
```

`pass` is a char array not a char variable. Use specifier `%s` for this .

These are causing problems.